# How do I use tabBarOnLongPress in bottom navigation(react navigation v5)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-navigation-v5

I couldnt find and example or snippets of how to use tabBarOnLongPress on react navigation v5.If somebody's done it already,help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using standard TabNavigator, just subscribe to `tabLongPress` event in your screen components.

```js
const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabLongPress', (e) => {
   // Do something
});
```

Example on Snack: https://snack.expo.io/HewmpqPQD

If you are using custom Tab Navigator, don't forget to emit `tabLongPress` event.

```js
const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };
```

More info here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/